# Invoke-WebRequest: Error fetching Ajax content

Tags: exception, powershell

I have a problem, that no one on google seemed to have before:

I'm trying to fetch the content of a webpage in PowerShell 3 with

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myUri -DisableKeepAlive
```

but I get a pop-up everytime that says `Error fetching Ajax content.<br/>Server Response: undefined`. I click OK and my script continues without complaint, but it pauses the execution, which is a problem.

I tried to run it with `PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden {myScript.ps1}`, and it suppresses the pop-up, but script execution stops, when it normally would appear.

I tried a `Try` `Catch` block, but it doesn't seem to get it.

It would be great if someone here had an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `-UseBasicParsing` switch on Invoke-WebRequest to avoid DOM processing of the returned HTML.

Comment: It's worth noting that -UseBasicParsing is required on Server Core installations of Windows; the DOM processing is done by the IE engine which is not installed by default on Server Core.